# How on my yii2 extension use messages for this extension?

Tags: yii2, internationalization, message, yii-extensions

How on my yii2 extension use messages for this extension?

On my module i used as belove, but after do it as extension it is not work

```
public function init()
{
    parent::init();
    $this->registerTranslations();
}


public function registerTranslations()
{
    Yii::$app->i18n->translations['vendor/abdualiym/yii2-contacts/*'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
        'sourceLanguage' => 'en',
        'basePath' => '@vendor/abdualiym/contacts/messages',
        'fileMap' => [
            'vendor/abdualiym/yii2-contacts' => 'contact.php',
        ],
    ];
}

public static function t($category, $message, $params = [], $language = null)
{
    return Yii::t('vendor/abdualiym/yii2-contacts/' . $category, $message, $params, $language);
}
```

```

Answer (score 0):

To have own messages in extension i did following:

- added to common config file:

  `'contact' => [
      'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
      'basePath' => '@vendor/abdualiym/yii2-contacts/messages',
      'sourceLanguage' => 'en',
      'fileMap' => [
          'contact' => 'contact.php',
      ],
  ],`

Then i use

```
Yii::t('contact', 'Text')
```